# No Task Reminders when created by Guest User

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, tasks, notification

We have a publicly  accessible Site. On that page, visitors are able to submit a form. This will create a Task with a reminder for a specific User.

The Problem that I have run into is, that Tasks created by the Guest User do not Trigger Lightning Notification Reminders for their Owner. The Notifications appear as normal, when the Tasks are submitted from this page by another User (not the Guest User).

**The page controller:**

```
public without sharing class TestController {

    public static void createTask () {
        Task t = new Task();
        t.ReminderDateTime = DateTime.now();
        t.IsReminderSet = true;
        t.Priority = 'High';
        t.Subject = 'Test Task';
        t.OwnerId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        t.Status = 'Open';
        insert t;
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a workaround for this behaviour?

Comment: which user are these tasks getting assigned to (ownerID) and are these tasks getting assigned correctly to that user  ?

Comment: @sf_user The tasks are getting assigned to a User, who is supposed to handle the request. They do get assigned correctly and  der reminder fields are set. When another user updates those tasks, without changing any fields, the notification appears currectly.

Comment: @StrayCheese Were you able to find the cause and solution?